# uniform convergence question3

Tags: real-analysis

Can any one show me why this definition work:
suppose the sequence {$f_n$} of real-value functions on the set E converges pointwise to $f$ on E. for each $n\in N$ , set $M_n = \displaystyle \sup_{x\in E} |f_n(x)-f(x)|$.   Then       {$f_n$} converges uniformly to $f$ on $E$ if and only if $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} M_n =0$ can anyone show me the proof Thanks so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The supremum norm, which you have defined as $M_n$, is basically the definition of uniform convergence.

> A sequence of real-valued functions $(f_n)$ is said to converge uniformly to $f$ if, for all $\epsilon > 0$, there is an $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $n \geq N$, $|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon$.

Note that you inherently have no $x$ dependence. This is the *uniform* part of the definition.

So suppose $\lim_n M_n = 0$. We wish to show that $f_n$ converges uniformly. Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. Our job is to find an $N$ large enough that $|f_n(x) - f(x) | < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$.

What do we know? Well, $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} M_n = 0$. Therefore, given $\epsilon > 0$, we can choose $N$ so large that $M_n < \epsilon$ for all $n \geq N$ (note $M_n \geq 0$ by assumption). Note that this bound does not depend on $x$ in any way. But, for any $x \in E$,

$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| \leq \sup_{x \in E} |f_n(x) - f(x)| = M_n(x) < \epsilon.$$

The above holds for all $n \geq N$, so we are done.

Can you show the reverse direction?

Comment: thanks so much, it very clear. i think i can show the reverse direction. and i totally understand this theorem

Comment: I'm glad it helped. General advice for analysis is: always write down what you the definitions of what you know and what you want to show. Half the difficulty is wrapping your head around the logical dependencies such as: *given* epsilon, *find* delta.